# Show xml code in page

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, xmldocument

I am trying to generate an API who returns info in xml format. When using the proper URL the XmlDocument is being generated properly but I have problems to show it and send it back. For example in http://maps.googleapis.com/ if I select a place I get the info and I can see it in the browser in a nice XML document.

```
<GeocodeResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<result>
<type>street_address</type>
<formatted_address>277 Bedford Avenue, Brooklyn, NY 11211, EE. UU.</formatted_address>
<address_component>
<long_name>277</long_name>
<short_name>277</short_name>
<type>street_number</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Bedford Avenue</long_name>
<short_name>Bedford Ave</short_name>
<type>route</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Williamsburg</long_name>
<short_name>Williamsburg</short_name>
<type>neighborhood</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Brooklyn</long_name>
<short_name>Brooklyn</short_name>
<type>sublocality_level_1</type>
<type>sublocality</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Kings County</long_name>
<short_name>Kings County</short_name>
<type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>New York</long_name>
<short_name>NY</short_name>
<type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Estados Unidos</long_name>
<short_name>US</short_name>
<type>country</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>11211</long_name>
<short_name>11211</short_name>
<type>postal_code</type>
</address_component>
<geometry>
<location>
<lat>40.7142320</lat>
<lng>-73.9612889</lng>
</location>
<location_type>ROOFTOP</location_type>
<viewport>
<southwest>
<lat>40.7128830</lat>
<lng>-73.9626379</lng>
</southwest>
<northeast>
<lat>40.7155810</lat>
<lng>-73.9599399</lng>
</northeast>
</viewport>
</geometry>
<place_id>ChIJd8BlQ2BZwokRAFUEcm_qrcA</place_id>
</result>
```

This is exactly what I want to make.

Here is how I created the xml:

```
                    XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDeclaration XmlDecl;
        XmlDecl = XmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "");
        XmlDoc.AppendChild(XmlDecl);

        XmlElement RootElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("cars");
        XmlDoc.AppendChild(RootElem);

        if (result.Count > 0)
        {
            XmlElement xmlCar;
            XmlElement xmlElem;
            XmlElement xmlSubElem;
            foreach (VehiculoResult item in result)
            {
                if (!(int.Parse(driver_age) < 21 && item.TipoSeguro == 2))
                {
                    string accris = CreateAccriscode(item);
                    xmlCar = XmlDoc.CreateElement("car");
                    RootElem.AppendChild(xmlCar);
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("Acrisscode");
                    xmlElem.InnerText = accris;
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("Description");
                    xmlElem.InnerText = "<![CDATA[" + item.Descripcion + "]]>";
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("Capacity");
                    xmlElem.InnerText = item.NumPlazas.ToString();
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                    DateTime fechaInicio = DateTime.Parse(pickup_date + " " + pickup_time);
                    DateTime fechaFin = DateTime.Parse(dropoff_date + " " + dropoff_time);
                    double price = UtilesReserva.ObtenerImporteReserva(TimeSpan.Parse((fechaFin - fechaInicio).ToString()),
                                                         item.PrecioHora, item.PrecioDia,
                                                         item.PrecioSemana, item.PrecioMes);
                    if (item.TipoSeguro == 2)
                    {
                        price += wService.CalcularPrecioSeguro(fechaInicio, fechaFin);
                    }
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("Price");
                    xmlElem.InnerText = price.ToString();
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("IncludedDistance");
                    if (item.LimitacionKM == 1)
                    {
                        xmlElem.InnerText = "250";
                    }
                    else if (item.LimitacionKM == 2)
                    {
                        xmlElem.InnerText = "500";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xmlElem.InnerText = "0";
                    }
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("IncludedDistanceUnit");
                    xmlElem.InnerText = "K";
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("IncludedDistanceType");
                    xmlElem.InnerText = "D";
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("ExtraDistancePrice");
                    xmlElem.InnerText = "0.15";
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("AptTax");
                    xmlElem.InnerText = "0";
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("AppTaxIncluded");
                    xmlElem.InnerText = "U";
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("YoungDrvFee");
                    xmlElem.InnerText = "0";
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("YoungDrvFeeIncluded");
                    xmlElem.InnerText = "Y";
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("FuelPolicy");
                    xmlElem.InnerText = "U";
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("Supplier");
                    xmlElem.InnerText = "Social Car";
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("Pickup");
                    xmlSubElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("Address");
                    xmlSubElem.InnerText = "<![CDATA[" + item.Direccion + "]]>";
                    xmlElem.AppendChild(xmlSubElem);
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("Dropoff");
                    xmlSubElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("Address");
                    xmlSubElem.InnerText = "<![CDATA[" + item.Direccion + "]]>";
                    xmlElem.AppendChild(xmlSubElem);
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("Image");
                    xmlElem.InnerText = item.UrlFotoPerfil;
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                    xmlElem = XmlDoc.CreateElement("Deep_link");
                    xmlElem.InnerText = "<![CDATA[" + item.Direccion + "]]>";
                    xmlCar.AppendChild(xmlElem);
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried using the following once I generate the Xml document:

```
        Response.ContentType = "text/xml"; //must be 'text/xml'
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; //we'd like UTF-8
        XmlDoc.Save(Response.Output);
```

And also the following:

```
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter);
        XmlDoc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
        xmlTextWriter.Flush();
        string result = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        saveText.Text = result; //saveText is the ID of a Label
```

Only the value that I put in InnerText appears but not all the xml code and I want to make appear everything. Anyone knows what I am missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking more and more I found the solution, it was just one line of code:

```
saveText.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(XmlDoc.InnerXml);
```

Hope it will help to others!